# Is this a typo in verb tense?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical

From [the article on French Wikipedia on J.R.R. Tolkien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien):

> *Tolkien commence à écrire pour son plaisir dans les années 1910, élaborant toute une mythologie autour de langues qu’il invente.*

Shouldn't *commence* be in passé simple, or imparfait?

And now that I look at it again… Shouldn't *“dans les années 1910”* be *“en l'année 1910”*? Or just *“en 1910”*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This particular use of *présent* is called *présent de narration* or *présent historique*, it describes a past event in the *présent* tense.

> **présent de narration ou présent historique** : il est employé dans les récits pour donner un relief particulier à un fait en le rendant plus présent à l'esprit du lecteur ou de l'auditeur. Il est généralement introduit par des temps du passé.
>
> - *Le 15 décembre 1926, il épouse Marie et convole en justes noces.*
> - *Hier, j'ai essayé de le convaincre. Je lui montre les papiers; il me rit au nez.*
>
> <sub>[Wikipédia fr](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9sent_(linguistique)#Fran.C3.A7ais)</sub>

In encyclopaedic texts, it is akin to the *présent de vérité générale*, used to talk about something that is always true, as in “*Tous les matins, le soleil se lève*”.

Answer (score 13):

In articles such as those, the present tense is very common. It also has the particularity of being called *présent historique*. Basically, it allows for a lighter text and can be mixed with *passé simple* to emphasize certain events. Wikipedia has a little [article on its pros and cons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9sent_(linguistique)#Avantages_et_inconv.C3.A9nients_du_pr.C3.A9sent_historique). You will most often find this kind of structure in history books or articles, hence its name.

As for your commented question, *dans les années 1910* is correct, as is *en l'année 1910*, although *en 1910* sounds more natural. However, the meanings are not the same. When you say *dans les années 1910*, it means "in the 1910s", so anywhere between 1910 and 1919. On the other hand, *en l'année 1910*, or *en 1910*, means "in 1910". It's specific to that year. So since it's probably difficult to pinpoint when exactly he first started to write, you approximate it.

Comment: +1 for actually answering both questions.